# Resize mat-raised-button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to reduce the size of mat-raised button. I thought I can reduce the size of the button by reducing the size of the text. But I'm unable to do so.

Here is the CSS:

```
button {
    margin-right: 1vw;
    background: #4285F4;
    color: white;
    font-size: 9px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

And the template:

```
<button mat-raised-button class="button"><span>Click here to submit</span></button>
```

Answer (score 8):

You're on the right track. In addition to font-size you also need to change line-height:

```
button{
    margin-right: 1vw;
    background: #4285F4;
    color: white;
    font-size: 9px;
    line-height: 18px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fmgfn1

Answer (score 1):

`Mat-raised-button` sets both `width` and `min-width` to 64px, you need to override both in your button CSS stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `width: auto;` to a specified unit such as `px`, `em` or `rem`.

For example change the width to `200px`

```
button {
    margin-right: 1vw;
    background: #4285F4;
    color: white;
    font-size: 9px;
    height: auto;
    width: 200px; 
}
```

Comment: changing the width and height reduces size but then the text is not at the center.

Comment: I only specified changing the `width`, not the height. By using the CSS in my answer, the text is center aligned.

Comment: But still the size is not small.I am trying to reduce both the height and width of the button keeping the text centrally aligned.

Comment: Ok, your comments are conflicting - is it that the text IS centered or is it NOT?  Your question was to resize the button, which I have provided an answer for. The text alignment was not mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

try to control with class not element and change the size like this example

```
.button {
margin-right: 1vw;
background: #4285F4;
color: white;
font-size: 9px;
height: 70px;
width: auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have tested and it doesnot work in Chrome unless you use the **!important** css declaration that is need to overide the material's one. The buttons will scale really nicely. The values are subject to your personal needs and you have to tune them.

```
    .varButton {
      margin-right: 1vw !important;
      font-size: 2.7vw !important;
      line-height: 3vw !important;
    }

    <button mat-raised-button type="submit" class="varButton">
```